Identifying 18-position connector
This is a connector on an Ortur Laser Master 2 Pro. It has 18 positions with 2 mm pitch. I've searched Digikey without much luck.


https://connectorbook.com/identification.html

"I've searched Digikey without much luck." I confirm that Digikey doesn't have it.
